# Specify constant range in solve

Tags: syntax

For example in:

```
Solve[r^2 - 4 r - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[r] == 0, r, Reals]
```

How can I specify a range for constant s, say between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 2):

As it can be read from the documentation add another equation or condition about some parameter in your equation:

```
Solve[r^2 - 4 r - s^2 - 4 s Sqrt[r] == 0 && 0<s<1, r, Reals]

(* {{r-> ConditionalExpression[2+s+2*Sqrt[1+s],0<s<1]}} *)
```